# How to create Admin Pages(Module) separate from DXA

Tags: dxa

I am using Java web application. My requirement is to create another application separate from the dxa project and CMS. We will use this for admin pages. It has its own scripts and styles. Url is something like 'http://webaddress/admin/settings.jsp' and so on. I am able to access the page but it doesn't load the styles and scripts properly. I get 406 error on the script that I access 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)

Comment: Basically, you will get a response based on the ACCEPT header that you set. Not so sure if it is a Tridion core question but it is a common error that you see while working with MVC and Json. Can you try some of the suggestions from here and post your results?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335591/spring-mvc-json-406-not-acceptable.